# Throw a format exception C#

Tags: c#, try-catch, formatexception

I'm trying to throw a format exception in the instance someone tries to enter a non-integer character when prompted for their age.

```
        Console.WriteLine("Your age:");
        age = Int32.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
```

I'm unfamiliar with C# language and could use help in writing a try catch block for this instance.

Thanks very much.

Comment: `Int32.Parse` will throw a `FormatException` if a non-numeric string is passed to it - your code looks like it does what you want it to?

Comment: Do you mean you're trying to `catch` a format exception?

Comment: Int32.Parse could return three different exceptions

Comment: this should help you http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173160(v=vs.80).aspx

Answer (score 24, accepted):

That code will already throw an `FormatException`. If you mean you want to *catch* it, you could write:

```
Console.WriteLine("Your age:");
string line = Console.ReadLine();
try
{
    age = Int32.Parse(line);
}
catch (FormatException)
{
    Console.WriteLine("{0} is not an integer", line);
    // Return? Loop round? Whatever.
}
```

However, it would be *better* to use `int.TryParse`:

```
Console.WriteLine("Your age:");
string line = Console.ReadLine();
if (!int.TryParse(line, out age))
{
    Console.WriteLine("{0} is not an integer", line);
    // Whatever
}
```

This avoids an exception for the fairly unexceptional case of user error.

Comment: I'm a little confused by this line: if (!int.TryParse(line, out age)

Comment: @user1513637: In what way? `int.TryParse` returns whether or not it was successful, and store the result in the `out` parameter. See the documentation for details.

Answer (score 3):

What about this:

```
Console.WriteLine("Your age:");
try
{    
     age = Int32.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
}
catch(FormatException e)
{
    MessageBox.Show("You have entered non-numeric characters");
   //Console.WriteLine("You have entered non-numeric characters");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

No need to have a try catch block for that code:

```
Console.WriteLine("Your age:");
int age;
if (!Integer.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out age))
{
    throw new FormatException();
}
```

Answer (score -1):

you can do this...

```
int age;
```

Console.WriteLine("Your age:");
age=Conver.ToInt32(Console.Readline());

//@Erfunll

Comment: The original author was asking for help on how to write a try/catch. Your answer might be improved by showing him how to do this.

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour). Thanks for answering but can you also add an explanation on how your code solves the issue? Also, check the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) for info on how to format code.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).