# I am getting a "Format Exception unhandled" error after running my code

Tags: c#

I am doing this project for my beginning c# class, and here is my code.

```
private void inTextBox_Leave(object sender, EventArgs e){
      const double inTextBox = 0.1;
      double num = double.Parse(this.inTextBox.Text);
      double doubledNum = num * inTextBox;
      string outStr = $"{doubledNum:D}";
      badTextBox.Text = outStr;
}
```

I am trying to make it so that when i tab out of my inTextBox that it will calculate a tip amount based on whether or not good service was provided during the hypothetical meal.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Throw a format exception C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12550184/throw-a-format-exception-c-sharp)

Answer (score 1):

use {doubledNum:F}

D is for integers, F for fraction.

see more here:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k(v=vs.110).aspx