# How to throw FormatException when the input is int instead of double?

Tags: c#, exception, formatexception

I have to throw FormatException if the GPA is entered as int instead of double, but I am not able to do it. However, I was able to throw FormatException when the decimal value is entered in studentID field. What I know is by default, double datatype accepts int value,and that is why it is not throwing exception, but I need to make sure the value entered as GPA is double.

```
using System;
using static System.Console;
// Declare a Student
// ID must be an integer and gpa must be a double to continue
namespace Debug4_4
{
    class Debug4_4
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            Student stu = new Student();
            bool areNumbersGood = false;
            while (!areNumbersGood)
            {
                try
                {
                    stu.setID();
                    stu.setGPA();
                    areNumbersGood = true;
                }
                catch (FormatException e)
                {
                    WriteLine(e.Message);
                    WriteLine("(Either the student ID or the GPA");
                    WriteLine(" was not in the correct format.)");
                    WriteLine("You will have to re-enter the student data.");
                }
            }
            WriteLine("Valid student");
        }
    }
    public class Student
    {
        private int stuId;
        private double stuGpa;
        public void setID()
        {
            string stuNumber;
            try
            {
                Write("Enter student ID ");
                stuNumber = ReadLine();
                stuId = Convert.ToInt32(stuNumber);
            }
            catch (FormatException fe)
            {
                throw (fe);
            }
        }

        //throw (fe);
        //}
        public void setGPA()
        {
            string stuGPAString;
            //string stuGPAString;
            try
            {
                Write("Enter student GPA ");
                stuGPAString = ReadLine();
                stuGpa = Convert.ToDouble(stuGPAString);

            }
            catch (FormatException fe)
            {
                throw (fe);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can't student have 4 GPA or 5 GPA? If the int value entered by user is convertible to double why you want to have this kind of validation?

Comment: `stuGpa` **IS** a double. What exactly is the problem? You've stated that you recognize that an `int` is convertible to a `double`, and you're storing the input in a `double` field. So you are already ensuring that the input is a `double`.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12550184/throw-a-format-exception-c-sharp

Comment: Smells like homework.  Rather than catching an exception to detect an error, try Integer.TryParse and throw your own exception on failure.

Comment: Also, if the only purpose of your `catch` is to `throw` the exact exception, then you really don't need the `try/catch` blocks at all. They aren't doing anything.

Comment: This is my homework assignment. I am asked to check if the GPA is entered as double, and throw necessary exception.

Comment: "I have to throw FormatException if the GPA is entered as int instead of double" - do you mean that you have to throw FormatException if the GPA is entered without a decimal point?

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming when you say the input must be double, you are expecting the input to have a decimal like 4.0 instead of 4. It is kind of an odd requirement, but if that is what you are looking for then you could achieve it by doing something like this. There might be better alternatives, but this will also do it

```
if (!(Double.TryParse(stuGPAString, out stuGpa) && stuGPAString.LastIndexOf(".") < (stuGPAString.Length - 1)))
{
    throw new FormatException("Invalid gpa");
};
```

but if you just want to validate if the gpa is Double and if not then throw FormatException, then use this

```
if (!Double.TryParse(stuGPAString, out stuGpa))
{
   throw new FormatException("Invalid gpa");
};
```

So your setGPA method will look like

```
    public void setGPA()
    {
        string stuGPAString;

        if (!Double.TryParse(stuGPAString, out stuGpa))
        {
            throw new FormatException("Invalid student gpa");
        };
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use GetType() method.

```
var x=10;
x.GetType(); => int
var x=10.0;
x.GetType(); => double
```